# W3C Standards compliant A name attribute replacement

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working making sites W3C standards complaint. There is an FAQ page which has a list of questions which is followed by the answers for the questions.

Each question is embedded in a hyperlink that has an HREF attribute with hash symbol a unique name containing a numerical index. For example `<a href='#q1'>Question 1</a>`, `<a href='#q2'>Question 2</a>`, etc...

At the beginning of each answer there is an a tag which has a name corresponding to the HREF in the question list. For example, `<a name='q1'></a>`, `<a name='q2'></a>`,  etc...

This allows the user to click on the question and navigate directly to the answer.

Additionally, there an A tag before the list of questions with the name top, `<a name='top'></a>`. Following each answer there is a hyperlink `<a href='#top'>Back to Top</a>` which users can click on to go back to the beginning of the list of questions.

However, when validating the page there is an error `The 'name' attribute on the 'a' element is obsolete. Consider putting an 'id' attribute on the nearest container instead.`

How can this functionality be accomplished in HTML5 in a manner that is standards compliant?

Here is sample markup of the FAQ page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FAQs</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .faqqlist {list-style-type: decimal;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="faqqlist">
                <li><a href="#q1" class="faq faqq">Question 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#q2" class="faq faqq">Question 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#q3" class="faq faqq">Question 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#q4" class="faq faqq">Question 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#q5" class="faq faqq">Question 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="faqanswerlist">
            <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q1" name="q1"></a></p>
            <p>1.  Question 1</p>
            <p>Answer: </p>
            <div class="faqanswer">
                <p>Answer 1.</p>
            </div>
            <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>

            <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q2" name="q2"></a></p>
            <p>2.  Question 2</p>
            <p>Answer: </p>
            <div class="faqanswer">
                <p>Answer 2.</p>
            </div>
            <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>

            <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q3" name="q3"></a></p>
            <p>2.  Question 3</p>
            <p>Answer: </p>
            <div class="faqanswer">
                <p>Answer 3.</p>
            </div>
            <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>

            <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q4" name="q4"></a></p>
            <p>2.  Question 4</p>
            <p>Answer: </p>
            <div class="faqanswer">
                <p>Answer 4.</p>
            </div>
            <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>

            <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q5" name="q5"></a></p>
            <p>2.  Question 5</p>
            <p>Answer: </p>
            <div class="faqanswer">
                <p>Answer 5.</p>
            </div>
            <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from the issue you are asking about, this is way more concerning to me: `<a href="#top'>`. Mixing single and double quotes? Don't. Use double quotes and double quotes only.

Comment: For example, `<p><a class="faqanchor" id="q1" name="q1"></a></p>` put the `id="q1"` on the `p`, the question 1 `p` like `<p id="q1">1.  Question 1</p>` then remove the original `p` all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `id` attributes with the appropriate value on those elements (effectively duplicating the anchor name, which is not DRY). Just remove the `name` attribute and the page will continue working:

```
<div class="faqanswerlist">
    <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q1"></a></p>
<!--                        ^^^^^^^ -->
    <p>1.  Question 1</p>
    …

    <p><a class="faqanchor" id="q2"></a></p>
    <p>2.  Question 2</p>
    …
```

Alternatively you might consider wrapping each question in another element, and putting the `id` attribute on that. Given your structure, a list might be appropriate, but you can also just use `<div>`s:

```
<ol class="faqanswerlist">
    <li id="q1">
<!--    ^^^^^^^ -->
        <a class="faqanchor"></a>
        <p>Question 1</p>
        <p>Answer: </p>
        <div class="faqanswer">
            <p>Answer 1.</p>
        </div>
        <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
    </li>
    <li id="q2">
        <a class="faqanchor"></a>
        <p>Question 2</p>
        <p>Answer: </p>
        <div class="faqanswer">
            <p>Answer 2.</p>
        </div>
        <p class="faqtop"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
    </li>
    …
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like it is stated in the log:
Use`<div id="q1">...Answer 1...</div>`.
You can keep `<a href="#q1">` to navigate.
Most HTML functions which aren't included in HTML5 are kept in most browsers, but it isn't recommended.